# knockout validation and show tooltip

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have example web application with knockout.validation. I need show tooltip with message for required property - requiredText. I want create tooltip in viewmodel, not in html, but I can't?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ko.validation.test</title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Required field validation</h2>
        <div class="bs-docs-example">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="control-group" data-bind="validationElement: requiredText">
                        <label>Example 1 required</label>
                        <div class="input-append">
                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: requiredText" />
                            <button class="btn" data-bind="click: validateExample1Clicked">Validate</button>
                        </div>
                        <span class="label label-success" data-bind="visible: showExample1Success">Example 1 is valid</span>
                        <span class="label label-important" data-bind="visible: showExample1Failed">Example 1 is not valid</span>
                        <span class="help-inline" data-bind="validationMessage: requiredText"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group" data-bind="validationElement: requiredTextUsingAttributes">
                        <label>Example 2 required attribute</label>
                        <div class="input-append">
                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: requiredTextUsingAttributes" required />
                            <button class="btn" data-bind="click: validateExample2Clicked">Validate</button>
                        </div>
                        <span class="label label-success" data-bind="visible: showExample2Success">Example 2 is valid</span>
                        <span class="label label-important" data-bind="visible: showExample2Failed">Example 2 is not valid</span>
                        <span class="help-inline" data-bind="validationMessage: requiredTextUsingAttributes"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label>Optional</label>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: optionalText" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: validateAllClicked">Validate all</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="alert alert-error" data-bind="visible: showValidationErrors">
                        <strong>Not valid</strong> All the fields in the form are not valid.
                    </div>
                    <div class="alert alert-success" data-bind="visible: showValidationSuccess">
                        <strong>Valid</strong> All the fields are valid.
                    </div>
                    <div class="alert alert-info" data-bind="visible: errors().length > 0">
                        <strong>Form is not valid</strong> The form has following errors:
                        <ul data-bind="foreach: errors">
                            <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout.validation.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="ts/TestViewModel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/knockout.validation/knockout.validation.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts" />
var TestViewModel = (function () {
    function TestViewModel() {
        var _this = this;

        this.requiredText = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

        this.optionalText = ko.observable();

        this.requiredTextUsingAttributes = ko.observable();

        this.errors = ko.validation.group(this);

        this.showValidationErrors = ko.observable(false);
        this.showValidationSuccess = ko.observable(false);
        this.showExample1Success = ko.observable(false);
        this.showExample2Success = ko.observable(false);
        this.showExample1Failed = ko.observable(false);
        this.showExample2Failed = ko.observable(false);

        this.validateExample1Clicked = function () {
            if (!ko.validation.validateObservable(_this.requiredText)) {
                alert("rrrrrr");
// Create tooltip 
        };

        this.validateExample2Clicked = function () {
            if (ko.validation.validateObservable(_this.requiredTextUsingAttributes)) {
                _this.showExample2Success(true);
                _this.showExample2Failed(false);
            } else {
                _this.showExample2Success(false);
                _this.showExample2Failed(true);
            }
        };

        this.validateAllClicked = function () {
            if (_this.errors().length == 0) {
                _this.showValidationSuccess(true);
                _this.showValidationErrors(false);
            } else {
                _this.showValidationSuccess(false);
                _this.showValidationErrors(true);
            }
        };
    }
    return TestViewModel;
})();


ko.validation.init({
    parseInputAttributes: true,

    decorateElement: true,

    errorElementClass: 'error'
});

ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
//# sourceMappingURL=TestViewModel.js.map
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HTML:

<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout.validation.js"></script>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ViewModel.js"></script>

<style>
    body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    }
    fieldset {
        padding: 10px;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        width: 500px
    }
    label {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px
    }
    .validationMessage {
        color: Red;
    }
    .Warning {
        border-color: red;
    }
    .customMessage {
        color: Orange;
    }
    input {
        border:1px solid #ccc
    }
</style>

<div id="contain" class="container">
    <h2>Required field validation</h2>
    <input data-bind="value: lastName, tooltip: isValidField" data-placement="below" data-title="Alert" data-content="We have identified this information is incorrect and must be updated." />
    <button type="button" data-bind='click: submit'>Submit</button>
</div>


JavaScript:

ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.';
ko.validation.configure({
    //decorateInputElement: true,
    decorateElement: true,
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: false,
    insertMessages: false,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null,
    errorClass: 'Warning'
    //      errorAsTitle: true
});

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.lastName = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.isValidField = ko.observable();
    this.submit = function () {
        if (self.errors().length === 0) {
            alert('Thank you.');
        } else {
            self.errors.showAllMessages();
            self.isValidField(self.lastName.isValid());
        }
    };
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
};

ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            valueUnwrap = ko.unwrap(value),
            allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
            isValid = allBindings.value;
        if (isValid) {
            $(element).popover({
                trigger: "hover"
            });
        } else {
            $(element).popover("hide");
        }
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            valueUnwrap = ko.unwrap(value),
            allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
            isValid = allBindings.value;
        if (isValid) {
            $(element).popover({
                trigger: "hover"
            });
        } else {
            $(element).popover("hide");
        }
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var local = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            options = {};

        ko.utils.extend(options, ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip.options);
        ko.utils.extend(options, local);

        $(element).tooltip(options);

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).tooltip("destroy");
        });
    },
    options: {
        placement: "right",
        trigger: "hover"
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[extenders on observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)** to implement this kind of validation. Here's a sample implementation using the extender code from the Knockout documentation, just click *"Run code snippet"* to see a working demo:

**JS & HTML:**

```js
ko.extenders.required = function(target, overrideMessage) {
  //add some sub-observables to our observable
  target.hasError = ko.observable();
  target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

  //define a function to do validation
  function validate(newValue) {
    target.hasError(newValue ? false : true);
    target.validationMessage(newValue ? "" : overrideMessage || "This field is required");
  }

  //initial validation
  validate(target());

  //validate whenever the value changes
  target.subscribe(validate);

  //return the original observable
  return target;
};

function TestViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable('').extend({ required: "Required" });
}


ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label for="name">Name:</label>
<p data-bind="css: { error: name.hasError }">
  <input data-bind='value: name, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
  <span data-bind='visible: name.hasError, text: name.validationMessage'> </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

ko.validation has property: "insertMessages".

by defalut is true = show error in span near the element. for display error message in toolTip set value 'false' like this:

```
ko.validation.init{
    insertMessages: false
}
```